# Does aws block specific ip addresses based on any factor?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wifi, ip-address

Does AWS block specific IPs based on traffic or any other factor?
I see, lot of times I'm not able to access the AWS console from the devices connected to my home wifi network (In my case, wifi hotspot). I tried deleting cookies from browsers but that doesn't help either.

It is only getting resolved after I restart the Wi-Fi.

Is it common issue or is there any solution for this?

Note: I'm using **JIO** network - India.

Comment: I'm using the same (JIO network from my mobile hotspot), but I haven't encountered any problem accessing the AWS console. Which error message you got when the connection got failed. Which Account you're using Personal Account or Work Account. Have you tried to open the AWS account in the private/incognito window when you got an error from the normal window?

Comment: Error was: server’s ip address can’t be found. I tried incognito & other browsers too. It’s happening for both work & personal account.

Comment: Which OS you are using on your PC? If its windows have you changed the IPV4 properties of the WiIfi network?

Comment: @Arvin you are right!!! There's a "AWS blacklist". Same debian distro, same node installation, same node app. At home: OK. Different Server Farm brand: 403.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing at AWS side which blocks particular IP..100% damn sure..

This is might be issue of  your home network..

Comment: sure.
@achyutvyas, I will check on ipv4 settings. As for as I remember, I never touched those settings. Anyways thanks all. I will check and update back